# Output the field as $<field_name>_rendered in the node page

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

When a CCK field is added, we get the rendered output in the node page as `$<field_name>_rendered`.
How can we get a variable in the same way when we alter the form and add new field?

Comment: if i have created some extra fields using form alter in a content type and using node api i have saved them in a table i have created in database. if i need to get the output in the node page, i know that i have to use

function wsf_action_nodeapi(&$node, $op) {
if ($node->type == 'action') {
switch ($op) {
case 'view':

$node->content['my_field_name']="The content retrived form database";
break;
...
}
}
}

my question is when i use the cck to create a field in the content type, i can access the data in the node page as $my_field_name_rendered.

Comment: my question is when i use the cck to create a field in the content type, i can access the data in the node page as $my_field_name_rendered.
how can i load the value into $my_field_name_rendered when the node is rendered.

Comment: So you're altering the form to add a new CCK there ?  
Why don't you add the field in your Content Type and alter the form to make it disappear when you don't need it ? This way the rendering process will work as usual.

Comment: Tostinni.. i am adding a new field not a cck.

Comment: Do you have some code to enlighten us a little because it's quite difficult to understand what you're doing and what result you expect.

Comment: function satya_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
 if($form_id=='live_sports_node_form'){
  $form['p1']['#type'] ='textfield';
  $form['p1']['#title'] =t('textfield');
 }
} using this code i have added textfield and using nodeapi i have saved the value in a table custom_table and when the node loads in the frontend of the site all the field values that are created with cck will be available as $field_name and $field_name_rendured. My rquirment is if want the text value saved in custom_table to be returned as $p1_rendured in the node page how can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the data back to the node and render them, you first need to implement a [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) load. Here some a short example:

```
function satya_module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'load':
      // retrieve the p1 value from custom_table (it's better to use vid instead of nid to allow revisions.
      $p1 = db_result(db_query('SELECT p1 FROM {custom_table} WHERE vid = %d', $node->vid));
      return array('p1' => $p1);
      break;
  }
}
```

Then you will have a `$p1` variable available in your `node.tpl.php`.

If you don't know yet the [Examples modules](http://drupal.org/project/examples), I'll definitely recommends it to have great examples and developer documentation for a lot of hooks.